# iPhone 5 - Table View Header height not correct

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a CustomView for a Table View Header.

The height of the label within the Header is dynamic. For all simulators other than iPhone 5, it works. The Label text  works for any number of lines. The height increases changes to the correct required height.

But for iPhone 5 simulator, the header does not increase to appropriate height.

Is this an issue with iPhone 5 simulator? Don’t have a real iPhone 5 device to test this out.

Comment: Please include code or images, they are important to help the community debug any issue posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using autolayout to set the header height. You need to set the header height after the view has layout all the subviews.

```
  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.tableView.layoutHeaderView()
  }
```

Use this extension, it will adjust the header height to the required space:

```
extension UITableView {
  public func layoutTableHeaderView() {
    guard let headerView = self.tableHeaderView else { return }

    headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let headerWidth = headerView.bounds.size.width;
    let temporaryWidthConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "[headerView(width)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: UInt(0)), metrics: ["width": headerWidth], views: ["headerView": headerView])

    headerView.addConstraints(temporaryWidthConstraints)

    headerView.setNeedsLayout()
    headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

    let headerSize = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    let height = headerSize.height
    var frame = headerView.frame

    frame.size.height = height
    headerView.frame = frame

    self.tableHeaderView = headerView

    headerView.removeConstraints(temporaryWidthConstraints)
    headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
  }
}
```

Each time that you need to resize the height view call

```
self.tableView.layoutHeaderView()
```

It will adjust the table height view to the minimum space required, but it won't cut anything.

P.S: If you use autolayout to set the header height you need to define the distance between the label, the top of the headerView and the Bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the solution but still have the issue. What I have already works for every other Simulator - iPhone 5s and up. For any length of text in the header the label is sized, for height, correctly, and the Header Height is updated and the full text is seen. Only for iPhone 5 simulator, the height is not correct. Less than what is needed.

Comment: @SunilV Have you tried it in iPhone 4? (With the same size or smaller than iPhone 5?) Have you updated the layout of the table with self.tableView.layoutHeaderView() after adding the text to the label? And set the top and bottom margin to the container?

Comment: For iPhone 5 simulator, the header height is dynamic. But the only thing is, it calculates the height for a slightly smaller string. For example if the Label text is "This is a sample text for testing label" and iPhone 5 simulator needs 2 lines to show this, the size calculated with systemLayoutSizeFitting is for 1 line. Hence the second line is truncated. iPhone 5 also works sometimes. "This is a sample text for testing label, this should work" - Now this label text might get height of 3 lines (as required) for iPhone 5 simulator. And everything is fine in this case.

Comment: let height = header.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: self.bounds.size.width, height: 0), withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.required, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority.fittingSizeLevel).height

Comment: We don't support iPhone 4/4s. But will download iPhone 4s simulator and check the behavior.

Comment: The above height calculated is incorrect for iPhone 5. It calculates the height for a slightly smaller string than which is set. Longer strings do have increased height calculated for iPhone 5. Truncation happens when one or two words are wrapped to a new line and that new line is not shown as height is for 2 lines and the new line was the 3rd line.